# How do i display my data when overriding getview

Tags: android, listview, view, simpleadapter

Ive been learning about the getview . But i cant get it to display the data in my listview. Can anyone help code is below

```
//public class OrderProductSearch extends Activity {
public class OrderProductSearch extends Activity {
 ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    try{
        setContentView(R.layout.orderproducts);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //
        String shaw="";
        shaw = e.getMessage();
    }

    //Create view of the list where content will be stored
    final ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.orderproductlistview); 

    //Set for fast scrolling 
    listContent.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

    //Create instance of the database
    final DbAdapter db = new DbAdapter(this); 

    //Open the Database and read from it
    db.openToRead();

    //Routine to call all product sub groups from the database
    final Cursor cursor = db.getAllSubGroupProduct();
   //Manages the cursor
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    int i=0;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.getPosition() < cursor.getCount()) {
         item.put("ProdName",cursor.getString(2));
         item.put("ProdSize", cursor.getString(3));
         item.put("ProdPack",cursor.getString(4));
         item.put("OrdQty","0");

         //list.add(item);
         list.add(i, item);
         item = new HashMap<String,String>();   
         cursor.moveToNext();
        i = i + 1;

    }

    String[] from = new String[] {"ProdName", "ProdSize", "ProdPack", "OrdQty"};

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.productlinerow, R.id.productlinerow2, R.id.productlinerow3, R.id.productlinerow4};
    //SimpleAdapter notes = new SimpleAdapter(OrderProductSearch.this,list,R.layout.productlinerow,from,to);        
    NewAdapter notes = new NewAdapter(OrderProductSearch.this,list,R.layout.productlinerow,from,to);


    listContent.setAdapter(notes);


    //Close the database
    db.close();     


        }

class NewAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{
    int resource;
    Context cxt;
    private Context context;
    List<? extends Map<String, ?>> DataList;

    public NewAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
            int _resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, _resource, from, to);
        resource = _resource;
        this.context = context;
        DataList = data;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {            
        View v = convertView;

           if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.productlinerow, null);
           }

    //       TextView bTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productlinerow);
  //         bTitle.setText(DataList[position,1][1].toString());

        return v;
            }   

}






 }
```

Comment: You must extend CursorAdapter instead.

Comment: why? All my data is in a simple list which works fine untill i try the getview. By putting it in a array i can extra fields that isnt in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a SimpleAdapter, you don't need to extend the class and customize the getView() as the SimpleAdapter handles the mapping of data to your layout via the resource, from and to parameters.  Take a look at this tutorial for the idea:

http://vbsteven.com/archives/24

If you want to do more involved customization, use a BaseAdapter, which the SimpleAdapter actually extends.  Here's a tutorial with examples of that:

http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Comment: hi thanks for getting back to me. The problem is i have to use it as if you put a edittext box on the list view ( for user to add a qty) then you cant use a normal on click listener on the line you have to use the getview overide.

Comment: all im trying todo is display a list of products and a description and a qty box for them to add a qty on a listview cant belive this is so awkward to do.

Comment: Shouldn't be that awkward - create your layout row with the appropriate layout which will include a space for the text along with the EditText as well.   Then, extend a BaseAdapter class where you override the getView().  In there you'll inflate your EditText and user the addTextChangeListner() method to assign your listener.

Comment: ok thanks would the baseadapter display the data automatically in the getview or do i need to code it?

Comment: which brings me back to my orginal question how would i code that?